# Nginx Proxy Manager proxy_pass not working

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

On Nginx Proxy Manager I have this configuration (names redacted)

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# www.lab.myself.it
# ------------------------------------------------------------


server {
  set $forward_scheme http;
  set $server         "127.0.0.1";
  set $port           81;

  listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

  server_name www.lab.myself.it;

  access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-2_access.log proxy;
  error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-2_error.log warn;

  location /wiki/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass       http://maersk.lab.myself.it:8181/;

  }

  location / {
    # Proxy!
    include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
  }

  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}
```

Ideally I should be able to browse to http://www.lab.myself.it/wiki and Nginx should send me to http://maersk.lab.myself.it:8181.

The issue is that I get a simple webpage because the browser can't load CSS, JS or images.
When I try to click on a link on the wiki, it brings me to http://www.lab.myself.it/documentation <-- MISSING THE /WIKI/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up the base URL in your `wiki` application properly.